# Best ML model to pick similar objects

Tags: machine-learning

Let's assume I've got a list of objects with multiple features, all of which are labeled as positive, and use it as my training set. On the other hand I have the set I want to make predictions on which contains unlabeled objects (and there is no way to label them). What is the name of the algorithm I can used to find most similar objects to the ones in the training set?

Comment: Have you tried K nearest neighbours?

Comment: But how will this algorithm determine which objects are the closest, if we don't have any negative examples